# Syntax issue with adding creating a mongodb and user with roles

Tags: bash, mongodb, docker

I've started building my first docker container for a mongodb with auth.

I have a python script that fetches credentials from our password safe and makes them available for a bash script which then sets up the admin db and users.

I use a RUN command for the python script and that is fine.

The bash script run.sh runs perfectly when I log into the container and run it.

However, it should run as part of a CMD surely?

Dockerfile extract:

```
ADD set_mongo_passwords.py /
ADD run.sh /

RUN chmod +x /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /set_mongo_passwords.py

RUN python /set_mongo_passwords.py <user> <password>
CMD ["/bin/bash","/run.sh"]
```

Bash script

```
#!/bin/sh

mongod --auth

source mongodb_credentials.txt

# Wait for MongoDB to boot
RET=1
while [[ RET -ne 0 ]]; do
    echo "=> Waiting for confirmation of MongoDB service startup..."
    sleep 5
    mongo admin --eval "help" >/dev/null 2>&1
    RET=$?
done

echo "=> Creating admin user"
mongo admin --eval "db.createUser({user: '$MONGO_ADMIN_USER', pwd: '$MONGO_ADMIN_PASSWORD', roles:[{role:'userAdminAnyDatabase',db:'admin'}]});"

sleep 3

echo "=> Creating IawApi user"
mongo admin -u $MONGO_ADMIN_USER -p $MONGO_ADMIN_PASSWORD --eval "db.createUser({user: '$MONGO_IAWAPI_USER', pwd: '$MONGO_IAWAPI_PASSWORD', roles:[{role:'dbOwner',db:'IawApi'}]});"

echo "=> Creating vpnDebugger user"
mongo admin -u $MONGO_ADMIN_USER -p $MONGO_ADMIN_PASSWORD --eval "db.createUser({user: '$MONGO_VPNDEBUGGER_USER', pwd: '$MONGO_VPNDEBUGGER_PASSWORD', roles:[{role:'dbOwner',db:'vpnDebugger'}]});"

echo "Done!"

# delete anything that can be used to gain access to credentials

rm -f mongodb_credentials.txt
rm -f set_mongo_passwords.py
```

Comment: What about if you execute the command with RUN as opposed to CMD?

Comment: I tried a RUN but that runs during the build process and because the mongodb never came up the process hung as the bash script waits until the db is up to add the users. I may give another go while I'm out of ideas.

Comment: And with CMD "/bin/bash" "/run.sh"?

Comment: Nothing happens when using the CMD option.

Comment: Try it with ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: Thanks will give it a go :)

Comment: Still no joy I'm not a Linux guy am I missing something reall silly.

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","./run.sh"]

Comment: Try ENTRYPOINT [ "/run.sh" ]

Comment: Still no joy got a colleague to look while I'm holiday will answer this when I get back hopefully. Thanks for the help